# NullPointerException on TextView

Tags: android, layout, textview, nullpointerexception

I get a null pointer exception and the program crash on each time I want to update the highscore text using setText(). what causes this problem?
this code is when i set my layout, the layout is a part of the gameView using opengl, and I put the highscore textview on the upper left corner

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SFEngine.display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();//ambl ukuran width height layar
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    gameView = new SFGameView(this);
    gameView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));


    TextView textBox = new TextView(this);
    textBox.setId(1);
    textBox.setText("HIGH SCORE");
    textBox.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    textBox.setWidth(SFEngine.display.getWidth()/2);
    textBox.setHeight(50);
    Button pauseButton = new Button(this);
    pauseButton.setText("PAUSE");
    pauseButton.setHeight(50);
    pauseButton.setWidth(SFEngine.display.getWidth()/2);
    pauseButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
            //pause game
            SFEngine.isPlaying = false;
            Intent i1 = new Intent(SFGames.this, pause.class);
            gameView.onPause();
            startActivityForResult(i1,0);//hrs pk result soalny mw blk lg
            return true;
        }
    });


    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp_pause = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp_hs = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    lp_hs.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

    lp_pause.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    lp_pause.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

    textBox.setLayoutParams(lp_hs);
    pauseButton.setLayoutParams(lp_pause);

    layout.addView(gameView);
    layout.addView(textBox);        
    layout.addView(pauseButton);
    setContentView(layout);
```

and here is the setText code

```
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event){//buat nerima input user
    if(!SFEngine.isPlaying){
        finish();
    }
    textBox.setText("High Score :" + SFEngine.score);//here is the source of the prob
.....
```

error log:

```
 10-13 22:38:34.207: E/AndroidRuntime(528): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-13 22:38:34.207: E/AndroidRuntime(528): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-13 22:38:34.207: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at com.starfighter.SFGames.onTouchEvent(SFGames.java:136)
10-13 22:38:34.207: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at  android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2367)
```

UPDATE : 
i've updated the source code so the textview declaration is outside of the onCreate, it seems to be working normally now..

Comment: can you show us your error logs?

Comment: Debug your program and ensure that your SFEngine.score is not null.

Comment: at least post the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define the text view as a class field in the activity, outside the `onCreate`:

```
TextView textBox;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    textBox = new TextView(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `textBox` is a local variable in the `onCreate()` method. I think you have a member variable with the same name, too. So you actually using the wrong one.

Try to remove `TextView` in your `onCreate()`

```
// in onCreate
textBox = new TextView(this);
textBox.setId(1);
textBox.setText("HIGH SCORE");
```

Answer (score 0):

put TextView declaration outside of the onCreate()

```
TextView textBox;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    textBox = (TextView)findViewById(id.TextBoxNameFromLayout);
}
```

Comment: Can't use "this" before onCreate.

Answer (score -1):

Your textbox should be defined as global variable.

like this

```
class MyActivity extends Activity{
    TextView textBox = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        textBox = new TextView(this);
```

Comment: Please expand on your answer.

Comment: Please expand a bit, add in a code snippet to show what's wrong and what to do to fix, for example.

Comment: You should NEVER reference anything to do with an Activity outside the activity.  Globals are evil in most cases, putting a textview reference into a global will leak memory.

Comment: By the way - there is no "globals" in Java.